# Find the maximum numbers of rook to put in $6 \times 6$ board such that $2$ rooks don't attack each other?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question about probability but cannot find a good way to tackle it.

Here's the question:

Find the maximum numbers of rooks in the $6 \times 6$ board such that $2$ rooks don't attack each other?

My attempt: I can only think about guess and check method to solve this

First: We cannot put them adjacently or facing each other.

Second: I think the only way to put them in the board is diagonally, so the maximum rook To put is $6.$

Is my thought process correct or maybe somebody can provide a better way for me to tackle this problem? Thanks

Comment: I think your solution is right.

Comment: What on earth has this got to do with probability?

Comment: I cannot find a better tag,  maybe you can help me to edit it?  @almagest

Comment: @akusaja combinatorics is a better tag, I think.

Comment: Also, note that while this doesn't impact the validity of your solution, diagonal isn't the only way to place 6 rooks on the board.

Comment: " I think the only way to put them in the board is diagonally"  It is not the only way.  But it is *one* way.  And since the question was about how many rooks, the answer is $6$.  Because you *can* do six, and you *can't* do more.  That's all the question asks for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only $6$ columns.  So if you have more than $6$ rooks, at least two must be in the same column and therefore attacking each other.

So you can not have more than $6$.  So $6$ is a theoretical absolute maximum.  Now you have to prove that you *can* do $6$.

Which you can do if you put them diagonally

And you are *DONE* the maximum is $6$ because i) you *can* do $6$ and ii) you *can't* do more than $6$.

Nowhere in the question did you have to show that putting them diagonally is the only way.

Which it is not.

Not even remotely.

(Consider Rook 1 on $(a,2)$ and Rook 2 on $(b,1)$ and rooks $3$ to $6$ on $(c,3)$ to $(f,6)$).

In fact if you ever have Rook 1 on $(x, n)$ and Rook 2 on $(y, m)$ in a non-attacking way, you can switch to Rook 1 on $(x,m)$ and Rook 2 on $(y,n)$.

Are you sure that this was the actual question?

No offense but that seems way too easy, and it seems finding the total number of different ways to place the rooks (and not the number of rooks) is a much more interesting and relevant question.

There are $720$ ways to place $6$ rooks on a $6\times 6$ board where they aren't attacking each other.  Can you figure out why?

Comment: 720 is come from 6! ? Am i true? Thanks

Comment: Maybe I've made a mistake. The actual question maybe find the numbers of different ways.  Because the maximum rooks is 6, so I think the first step is only to ask about it.  So,  the different ways to put 6 rooks is 6!

Comment: It is.  But I didn't explain why.  But do you see it?

Comment: Ah, yes.  To place 6, you must have a rook in every row.  You can place the first rook in any column.  You can place the second rook in any *other* column,  You can place the third rook in any column except those occupied by the first two rooks. .... and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You started off well; to finish off, perhaps just concretize your intuition into a well-formulated argument such as the following:

You've already shown 6 is possible, so if we can show 7 is impossible, the answer is 6.

Now suppose there are 7 rooks on the board. There are only 6 rows, so one row must contain at least 2 rooks (this is called the Pigeonhole Principle, but even if you haven't heard of the name, you should be able to think through why this must be the case). But if there are at least 2 rooks in the same row, they are attacking each other! So 7 rooks will never work.

Since 6 works, but 7 (or more) never does, 6 is the maximum.